# What is the alternative for angular.copy in angular7?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Following code snippet:

```
toBarChart =  function (d){
  var tData = [{values: []}];
    angular.copy(d, tData[0].values)
  return tData;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: var deepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
This is one of the simplest way in native JS to deep clone an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply use the [Object.assign(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which will copy all the values of properties from the source to target object.

Let's see an example:

```js
(function() {
  let originalData = {
    title: 'example value'
  };

  let targetData = {};

  Object.assign(targetData, originalData);

  targetData.title = 'updated value';

  console.log('source and target', {
    original: originalData.title,
    target: targetData.title
  });
})();
```

In your case I assume you can do the following:

```js
toBarChart =  function (d){
  var tData = [{values: []}];
    Object.assign(d, tData[0].values)
  return tData;
}
```

Comment: `Object.assign` is also the fastest way to clone an object: http://jsben.ch/bWfk9

Answer (score 1):

lodash is good for deep copying in Angular

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

let newCopy = _.cloneDeep(objectToBeCopied);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try `cloneDeep` function from `lodash`.

Comment: Which one is `_`? `lodash`or `underscore`?